# Python - how to iterate over the first characters of strings in a list

Tags: python

In a list that I have, I want to find all elements that begin with a digit and copy them to another list. This is the code I wrote:

```
with open("p.txt") as f:
  lineList = f.read().splitlines()

  numLines = len(lineList)

newFile = []

for i in range(numLines):
    if lineList[i][0].isnumeric():
        newFile.append(lineList[i])
```

unfortunately, the compiler returns `IndexError: string index out of range` because of [0] in the second last line of code.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You have an empty line in your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong with my code?

@Sayse really answered your question in his comment.

How you fix it is up to you. You can either remove the empty line(s) from the file or handle them:

```
for line in lineList:
    if len(line)>0 and line[0].isdigit():
        newFile.append(line)
```

Comment: Thank you. Removing the empty lines wasn't possible, because the whole point of the script is to avoid modifying a big number of files by hand.

Using your code solved the problem. This is my very first script in Python and I see I have to work on my syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This should happen whenever one of your lines is empty, resulting in a empty list as well []. Since the first entry of an empty list is already out of range, you get your error. An easy way to fix this is add an if condition, checking if the line is not empty. If it isn't, proceed as usual:

```
with open("p.txt") as f:
  lineList = f.read().splitlines()

  numLines = len(lineList)

newFile = []

for i in range(numLines):
    if len(lineList[i])>0:             #This is the changed line.
        if lineList[i][0].isnumeric():
            newFile.append(lineList[i])
print(newFile)
```

If you have additional questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the usage of list comprehensions especially when the ouput is going to be another list.

For example

```
import re

L = ['10_help', 'help', '1_ec']
[rec for rec in L if re.search('^\s*[0-9]',rec)]
```

[When List comprehension is an answer](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-list-comprehensions-can-help-your-code-look-better-and-run-smoother-3cf8f87172ae)

Answer (score 1):

As noted elsewhere, you have an empty line in your file. You could handle this by changing your `if` to:

```
    if lineList[i] and lineList[i][0].isnumeric():
```

`lineList[i]` will only be `True` if it is non-empty and, if `False`, Python will not evaluate the second part of the `and` statement (this is called Early Termination) so you will not get the error.

Your use of a counter to loop through the lineList isn't the Pythonic approach to looping through a file. You could in fact simplify the loop further to:

```
for line in lineList:
    if line and line[0].isnumeric():
        newFile.append(line)
```

That could be simplified even further to a list comprehension:

```
newFile = [line for line in lineList if line and line[0].isnumeric()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list comprehension in combination with `.isdigit()`:

```
lst = ['test', '212122', '', '123_test']
new_lst = [item for item in lst if item and item[0].isdigit()]
print(new_lst)
```

This yields

```
['212122', '123_test']
```

---

Or with your file handle

```
with open("p.txt") as f:
    lineList = f.read().splitlines()
    new_lst = [item for item in lineList if item and item[0].isdigit()]
```